# Hiding Divs Within Divs

Tags: jquery, html

I am not sure why the following code doesn't hide my two divs within my div for my content.  Can someone check my code?  The code doesn't hide either div below.  Thanks

OK, Here is my edited code.  At initialize load both forms appear under the select Type, when I select dealer/customer the correct form shows and select type then shows Nothing after you select one.  How do I get it to hide everything initially?  Thanks

```
<div id="contentArea">
            <form action="xxxxx.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkStuff();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Warranty Registration Type:<br/>
                <select id="select"> 
                    <option value ="#blank">Select Type</option>
                    <option value ="#dealerform">Dealer</option>
                    <option value ="#customerform">Customer</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <div id="dealerform">
                    Dealer Name:   <input type="text" name="dealername"> <br/>
                    Dealer Address:  <input type="text" name="dealeradd"> <br>
                </div>
                <div id="customerform">
                    First Name:  <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>
                    Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastname"> <br>
                </div>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#select').change(function(){
                        $('#dealerform,#customerform').hide();
                        $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
                    });
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: `$('#select')` should be   `$('select')`

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because your select doesn't have the id 'select' that you use in the change event.

```
                <select id="select"> 
                    <option value ="#dealerform">Dealer</option>
                    <option value ="#customerform">Customer</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you should write like this

```
 $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
```

instead of this

```
 $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')).show();
```

so that corresponding div will hide ofcourse as others said need to add id for select or remove # before the select

```
$('select').change(....)
```